# running tests from node against selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker

I just set up Selenium hub and Selenium-hub/node-chrome(linked to hub) docker containers. However, am not sure how I can start running my tests right now from a new container, for instance I just set up a node container with this some tests running on it(which doesn't work)...

```
var chai = require('chai')
var chaiProm = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(chaiProm)
var expect = chai.expect

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')


var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    // .setChromeOptions(/* ... */)
    // .setFirefoxOptions(/* ... */)
    .build();

console.log(driver)

describe("website general checks",function(){
 beforeEach(function(){
  driver.get('google.com')
})
afterEach(function(){
  driver.quit()
})

....
```

I just want to know if am in the right direction of how I should run my tests.

Comment: You may refer to a python simple test run here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126945/248616

Comment: How are you running your containers?